# Get System Info which WMI does not return - C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program which return some system info. I'm using WMI in C# but it seems it can not return all information needed.

For example I need the system Ram info, Here is what WMI returns:

[image]

and Here what another program returns:

[image]

WMI can not return "Manufacture" or "MemoryType", so How can I retain such Info?

Comment: http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf

Comment: @celerno that's Perl, this is C#!!

Comment: @JeremyThompson sorry, didn't saw the tag. I usually pay attention to the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
 connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\CIMV2", connection); 
 scope.Connect(); 
 ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
 foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) 
 { 
 Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
   foreach (PropertyData data in queryObj.Properties)
    Console.WriteLine(data.Name + "\t" + data.Value); 
 }
```

Comment: thanks but it will not return full info. I used CPU-Z application and it returns RAM's manufacture but WMI can not.